# PHP Combining Two PDFs Script Returns First Page Combined Twice

Tags: php, session, pdf, post, tcpdf

I've got a php script that merges two PDF files. The script works perfectly when I pull the two files directly from the server. But the point is to post the two treat the it as a service and post the two files as a base 64 encoded text and then the merge the files and let the receiving end download the combined PDF.

When using the post variables, I get mixed results. I think something is stuck in cache or in the session, but I'm not too familiar with how to correctly make this happen.

When the result is incorrect, it is first PDF combined twice. I started to check if PDF1 = PDF2 and throw an error, but it never happens when testing unless I actually post the same PDF. I've tried further tests in the script, but cannot identify a point of error.

How else can I debug this? What else can I try?

Here's the current script:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PDFMerge/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PDFMerge/tcpdf/tcpdi.php');


class MergePDF extends TCPDI 
{
    public $files = array();

    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function concat()//from set assign example
{
    foreach($this->files AS $key=> $file) {
        $pageCount = $this->setSourceData($file);//setSourceData used for raw data
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
             $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
             $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplIdx);
             $this->AddPage($s['w'] > $s['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
             $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
        }
        if($key>0){
            if ($this->files[0] == $this->files[1]){
            echo "Duplicate file error"; //I cannot get this to occur
            die();
            }                   
        }
        unset($file);
        unset($pageCount);
    }
}


}

//error_log("MergePDF Called");

$pdf641 = $_POST['pdf1'];
$pdf642 = $_POST['pdf2'];
$outputType = $_POST['output'];


if ($pdf641 == $pdf642)
{   
    echo "error: both files are the same";
    error_log("MergePDF error: Both Files are The Same!");
    session_unset();
    die();
}

/*

if (hash("sha256",$pdf641,false) == hash("sha256", $pdf642,false))
{
        echo "error: both files are the same";
        error_log("MergePDF error: Both SHA256 Files are The Same!");
        die();
}
*/


$p1d = base64_decode($pdf641);
$p2d = base64_decode($pdf642);

$pdf = new MergePDF();
$pdf->setFiles(array( $p1d, $p2d));

$pdf->concat();

$uuid = uniqid("pdf_",false);

if ($outputType == "download")
{
    $pdf->Output($uuid . '.pdf', 'I'); /*//D I*/ 
}
else
{
    $out = base64_encode($pdf->Output($uuid . '.pdf', 'S')); //output is 'S' for string 
    echo $out;
}

?>
```

Comment: Not to nitpick but why are you using a session at all? Their doesn't appear to be any session data in your code. Also their is no caching taking place in your code. Your output also looks like it needs a header `header('Content-type: application/pdf ');`

Comment: @danielson317 I was trying different things with sessions, but nothing was correcting the problem. If local variables are enough, I can get rid of all session calls. What would be causing my problem?

Comment: Not sure what's causing your problem. I do find it odd you are using `$_POST['pdf1']` instead of `$_FILES['pdf1']`. PHP typically uses the files super global for file uploads. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @danielson317 the system making the request to the service needs to POST the PDF data encoded in the URL string. My results are random, sometimes I get the correct result and the other times I get the first PDF merged twice.